# Resize image canvas with CodeIgniter Image Library - how to preserve transparency

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

I am trying to resize image canvas (as in Photoshop) by adding transparency around it. Somehow added part of the image is always black.

```
if ($this->image_library == 'gd2' AND function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor'))
{
     $create = 'imagecreatetruecolor';
     $copy = 'imagecopyresampled';
}
else
{
     $create = 'imagecreate';
     $copy    = 'imagecopyresized';
}

$dst_img = $create($this->width, $this->height);

if ($this->image_type == 3) // png we can actually preserve transparency
{
    //teorethicaly image should be transparent?
    $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst_img, 0, 0 ,0, 127); 
    imagefill($dst_img, 0, 0, $trans_colour);
    imagealphablending($dst_img, FALSE);
    imagesavealpha($dst_img, TRUE);
}

$copy($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $this->x_axis, $this->y_axis, $this->width, $this->height, $this->orig_width, $this->orig_height);
```

If I remove `$copy` and save new image only, it is transparent but if I merge both images the background is always black:

[image]

How I can have transparent background in that situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its `&&` not `AND` in if conditions

Comment: I believe that this part doesn't affect anything - it goes inside the condition, and this part is untouched code from CodeIgniter library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.akemapa.com/2008/07/10/php-gd-resize-transparent-image-png-gif/ http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=232090.0 How to preserve transparency when resizing PNG using Perl and GD.